# STUFF, UNPIVOT and group By clause on data

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, unpivot

Actual Data is In the Following Format:

```
Id       |  Disclosure  | Photo DisclosureDate | Community Trip Disclosure | Assum Of Risk Disclosure | Release Of Info | Photo DisclosureDate
1        |   2017-05-03 | 2017-05-03           | 2017-05-03                | 2017-05-03               | 2017-05-03      | 2017-05-03
2        |   2017-05-03 | 2017-05-03           | 2017-05-03                | 2017-05-03               | 2017-05-03      | 2017-05-03
```

Used the UNPIVOT to get the data in separate rows from each column (Dates could be different so for each unique date want comma-separated column names):

```
SELECT Id, t1.ExpiringOn ,DisclouserName
    FROM (SELECT Id, ParticipantName, ExpiringOn, DisclouserName FROM (
        SELECT P.Id, P.LastName + ', ' + P.FirstName as 'ParticipantName', TSL.PhotoDisclosureDate, TSL.CommunityTripDisclosureDate, TSL.AssumOfRiskDisclosureDate, TSL.ReleaseOfInfoDate, TSL.DisclosureDate
        FROM RegistrationDisclosures AS TSL
        INNER JOIN RegistrationParticipantInfo AS P with (nolock) ON P.Id = TSL.ParticipantId 
        where P.IsActive = 1 and (TSL.PhotoDisclosureDate < GETDATE() or TSL.CommunityTripDisclosureDate < GETDATE() or TSL.AssumOfRiskDisclosureDate < GETDATE() or TSL.ReleaseOfInfoDate < GETDATE() or TSL.DisclosureDate < GETDATE())
    ) d
    UNPIVOT
    (
        ExpiringOn for DisclouserName in (PhotoDisclosureDate, CommunityTripDisclosureDate, AssumOfRiskDisclosureDate, ReleaseOfInfoDate, DisclosureDate)
    ) upvt) t1
```

Result Using UNPIVOT:

```
Id       |  Expiring Date  | Disclouser
1        |   2017-05-03    | Photo DisclosureDate
1        |   2017-05-03    | Community Trip Disclosure
1        |   2017-06-03    | Assum Of Risk Disclosure
1        |   2017-06-03    | Release Of Info
2        |   2017-07-03    | Photo DisclosureDate
```

Expected Result:

```
Id       |  Expiring Date  | Disclouser
1        |   2017-05-03    | Photo DisclosureDate, Community Trip Disclosure
1        |   2017-06-03    | Assum Of Risk Disclosure, Release Of Info
2        |   2017-07-03    | Photo DisclosureDate
```

Trying to use STUFF but not able to Group items in STUFF command.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Sample data would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
WITH x as (<your query here>)
SELECT x.id, x.expiringon,
       STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + DisclouserName
               FROM x x2
               WHERE x2.id = x.id
               FOR XML PATH ('')
              ), 1, 2, ''
            )
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, expiringon FROM x) x;
```

This is the XML version for aggregate string concatenation.  The most recent version of SQL Server finally offers a `string_agg()` aggregation function.